# C++ std::vector - How to modify an element specified by an iterator?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to change each element of a vector, but my code doesn't compile, because of some confusion over `const`s. Here is a greatly simplified example (I have omitted the initialization of the vector):

```
std::vector<int> test;
for (auto iter = test.cbegin(); iter != test.cend(); ++iter)
{
    int v = *iter; // gets the correct element
    *iter = v * 2; // compile error
}
```

The compiler error is "'iter': you cannot assign to a variable that is const". What is the correct way to modify a single element, using iterators as shown?

Comment: `cbegin` - If you want to modify, don't use constant iterators.

Answer (score 11):

You specifically asked compiler to make sure you **will not** modify the content of the vector by using `cbegin()`.

If you want to modify it, use non-const functions:

```
for(auto iter = test.begin(); iter != test.end(); ++iter)
{
    int v = *iter; // gets the correct element
    *iter = v * 2; // works
}
```

Or shorter version of the above loop using range-based loop:

```
for(auto& v : test)
{
    v *= 2;
}
```

---

There is a difference between types of iterators:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator a // not allowed to modify the content, to which iterator is pointing
*a = 5; //not allowed
a++; //allowed

const std::vector<int>::iterator b //not allowed to modify the iterator itself (e.g. increment it), but allowed to modify the content it's pointing to
*b = 5; //allowed
b++; //not allowed

std::vector<int>::iterator c //allowed to both modify the iterator and the content it's pointing to
*c = 5; //allowed
c++; //allowed
```

Comment: maybe in the range-for change the name from `iter` to `elem` or something similar. You get the element with range-for, not an iterator.

Comment: OK, I see what happened, but I have to say it is confusing. I am not changing the vector, in the sense that its size, allocations, and element positions and element sizes are not being changed, only some bits within each element.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about range-for. Can you explain further?

Comment: @Woody20 a `const_iterator` is like a pointer-to-const. You can't change the data being pointed at. And the comment about the range-for loop refers to the name of the loop variable. In `for(auto iter : test)`, it doesn't make sense to name the variable `iter` because a range-for loop does not let you acccess the iterator being used, only the element that the iterator refers to